# OAuth 2 Callback Code

Tags: wordpress, oauth-2.0

I am working on a WordPress plugin that requires the use of OAuth 2. So far I've included the necessary OAuth files in an include folder in my plugin, put in the ClientId, ClientSecret I've obtained, and was able to authorize the app. After I authorized the app I received a callback code that I am supposed to use to get the token I assume. I put that code in my plugin, refreshed the page, and saw the information that is supposed to be outputted. When I go to a different page, it tells me that I am not authorized to view the information because the access token may be missing. So essentially it feels like the code that is sent to retrieve the token is only able to be used once. Do I need to store the token somehow? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In OAuth2 three-pass procedure the auth_code must be used only to obtain the access token
invoking a specific URL of the authentication server. The access token obtained can be used to access the pages later, as long as it is valid.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Do I need to get the access token and make it a variable then call it every time I reference the API? It works right the first time but the authentication server doesn't give me permission to use it again unless I reauthorize and get a new auth_code. I am new to OAuth so please excuse my questions.

Comment: When you request the access token to the authentication server also get some information such as the expiration and the refresh token (to renew once expired). All this information must be stored locally. You must use the same access token as long as it has not expired.

Comment: By locally do you mean as a cookie for instance? Thanks for your help!

Comment: "locally" I mean in a local storage, i.e. database.

Comment: I see. Would have to make it so the plugin stores the access token in the database. Thanks again!